# how to center images inside the div

Tags: css

Im trying to center the images inside the .pics div, but the css does not work

```
<article class="pics"> 
         <ul>
            <li><img class="default" alt="cake" src="images/IMG_2774_opt.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="default" alt="cake" src="images/198_opt.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="default" alt="cake" src="images/IMG_2774_opt.jpg"></li>
         </ul>  
</article>
```

CSS: `.pics {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

Does not work

Comment: Must have a height property if you want to vertically align things.

Comment: Try adding the CSS for the unordered list and images or perhaps a link to a live example. It will help greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point you to a really simple solution

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
...
<IMG class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bth9g/

HTML:

```
<div class="center" >
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="img"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:black;
    display:table;
}
.centered{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.img{
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```